# Permission Issue with starting react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have an issue with web app running on react, In fact, react fail to start on browser and sone error in terminal.

Can you help please.

```
       /app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:281
node_1         |                                throw err;
node_1         |                                ^
node_1         | 
node_1         | Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/app/public/build/fonts/palmhr.8008cff1.ttf'
node_1         |     at Object.unlinkSync (fs.js:956:3)
node_1         |     at rimrafSync (/app/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:314:17)
node_1         |     at /app/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:350:5
node_1         |     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
node_1         |     at rmkidsSync (/app/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:349:26)
node_1         |     at rmdirSync (/app/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:342:7)
```

Comment: Does this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877975/how-to-solve-permission-denied-error-with-react-native Granted, this is react-native, but the issue you are facing is related to file permissions, so this is relevant either way.

Comment: no its not the same