# React-native Error: Invalid `Podfile` file: exit. "couldn't install Pods. Updating the Pods project and trying again..."

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

Podfile:

```
use_modular_headers!

#platform :ios, '15.0'  # Specify the minimum iOS version
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

target 'copiaReactnativeApp' do
  use_react_native!(
    :path => use_native_modules![:reactNativePath],
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",
    :hermes_enabled => true
  )

  target 'copiaReactnativeAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_path = use_native_modules![:reactNativePath]
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      react_native_path,
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
  end
end
```

And I would get this error:

```
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `copiaReactnativeApp`: Picker, RNCMaskedView, RNCPicker, RNFBApp, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNScreens, react-native-config, react-native-image-picker, and react-native-safe-area-context
Framework build type is static library

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: exit.

 #  from {path}/ios/Podfile:13
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  target 'copiaReactnativeApp' do
 >    use_react_native!(
 #      :path => use_native_modules![:reactNativePath],
 #  -------------------------------------------

[!] Unable to remove the content of {path}/copia-react-native-app/ios/../ios/build/generated/ios folder. Please run rm -rf {path}/copia-react-native-app/ios/../ios/build/generated/ios and try again.
```

Then I tried adding:

```
plugin 'react_native_post_install', {
  'react_native_path' => '../node_modules/react-native',
  'use_modular_headers' => true
}
```

and

```
platform :ios, '15.0'

target 'copiaReactnativeApp' do
  use_react_native!(
    :path => '../node_modules/react-native',
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",
    :hermes_enabled => true
  )
end
```

Error:

```
Your Podfile requires that the plugin `react_native_post_install` be installed. Please install it and try installation again.
```

I have tried uninstalling Cocoapods and reinstalling, Ive tried these as well:

npx pod-install, pod install, gem install cocoapods-react-native-post-install, gem update --system, pod cache clean --all, bundle install, pod setup

I am able to run my app still by using `npm start` and then opening my simulator. It does give me this error though:

```
Error: xcodebuild: error: Unable to read project 'copiaReactnativeApp.xcodeproj'.
```

Versions

---

react-native: 0.73.4

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Ruby: 3.0.0

Cocoapods: 1.15.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing the following

1. run `whoami` to get the current user.
2. run: `sudo chown -R ownerName: /path/to/node_modules`

I found it from this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57561067/11393599).